# CSS inline gallery / max-width: 100% = Scrollbar does not appear

Tags: html, css, safari, slider, gallery

I am trying to create a CSS inline gallery.

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <ul>
        <li><img src="http://placehold.it/500x50" alt="" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://placehold.it/500x50" alt="" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://placehold.it/500x50" alt="" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://placehold.it/500x50" alt="" /></li>
        <li><img src="http://placehold.it/500x50" alt="" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
  width: auto\9;
  height: auto;
}

html,
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    background: grey;
    text-align: center;
    overflow: scroll;
}

ul {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

li {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100%;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6fjV9/1/)

The problem I am facing is that its not working (d'oh). The idea is to have `#wrapper` set to `width: 100%;` and then having the images aligned horizontal in one line inside `#wrapper`. To navigate between the images, a horizontal scrollbar can be used.

But as you can see, no scrollbar appears, the overflow is simply hidden.
While debugging I found that the following rule on the `img` elements causes the problem: `max-width: 100%;`. If you remove that, the scrollbar appears but the images aren't centered anymore.

As it is a responsive site, I also can't simply remove `max-width: 100%;`. So basically, I am stuck and don't know that to do. I don't even know why `max-width: 100%;` messes up the scrolling.

Can you please help me?

Edit: So in Safari 6.0.2., no scrollbar appears, but in Firefox 19.0.2 everything seems fine. To me things get stranger and stranger.

Comment: I see the horizontal scrollbar :|

Comment: @AndreaLigios Thanks for your comment. I just checked the Fiddle in Firefox 19.0.2 and indeed, everything is fine there, but not in Safari 6.0.2.

Comment: I think the problem is in Safari only. Chrome & FF works for me.

Comment: In Safari I see the scrollbar disabled because it displays only one image.

Comment: Since its a Safari problem, you might want to look into  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8946869/force-scrollbar-on-safari

Comment: Ok... sorry I don't have Safari installed. But it does seems a lot of code for the purpose... and what is `width: auto\9;` :O

Comment: I've added Safari tag, hopefully more people will come to help. P.S: You may want to use `overflow-x: scroll` instead of simple overflow...

Comment: @AndreaLigios `width: auto\9;` is a CSS hack for IE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't safari per say, here's a working solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/6fjV9/2/

```
#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    background: grey;
    overflow: scroll;
}

ul {
    display: table;
    width: 2500px;
    height: 50px;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

li {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}

img {
    display: block;
}
```

You set your list's width to 100% of its parent, which just takes the viewport size, as its own width is also 100%. The list must have the width of all its children in a line, e.g. `5 * 500 = 2500`. While FF seems to just resize the "table" to its content (maybe `table-layout: fixed;` is an important style property here), safari keeps its size at 100%, causing no scrollbars as it's just as wide as its parent.

**Update**: Or just set no width at all with display: table. http://jsfiddle.net/6fjV9/4/

Comment: Ah I see, thank you! So on another note if somebody else runs into this issue: https://coderwall.com/p/tctqaa does not necessarily brings any advantages! "don't use wrapper with width of 20000 pixels" Thats wrong I believe, as the Fiddle above clearly shows that such a wrapper width is needed .

Comment: Well I haven't tried to set no width at all to be honest, but it should work, try it out ;).