# Prevent defaults using CSS

Tags: css, default

I have used the following CSS code ([from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8946869/force-scrollbar-on-safari)) to display scroll bar in safari (mobile view).

```
.myScroll {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 8px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background-color: rgba(240,240,240, .6);
    border-radius: 8px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 8px;
    background-color: rgba(156, 156, 156, .6);
}

::-webkit-scrollbar{
    -webkit-appearance: initial;
}
```

Now I want to see the default scroll bar in desktop view. What should I add to my desktop CSS code?

**P.S.** I'm not supposed to use media queries in CSS. I already have different CSS files for different resolutions.

Comment: I'm using media queries, but styling for mobile view reflects in desktop also. :)

Comment: So you're using wrong media queries. Give us the whole source.

Comment: « *not supposed to use media query in css. I already have different css files for different resolutions* » — how are you doing this? Without showing us how you're doing it, we can't tell you how it's going wrong.

Comment: `I already have different css files for different resolutions.`...sounds like media-query concept to me.....clear your head dude...whats your requirement!! :)

Comment: Your solution is wrong. Your solution creates a few HTTP requests, instead of only one. You should combine your CSS files into one file.

Comment: i'm using scss where i have a file which imports scss files of different resolutions using media queries. I'm not supposed to use media query now in resolution scss.

Answer (score 0):

use `@media (max-width: 640px)` or other width value and use you css inside it:

```
@media (max-width: 640px){
     your css code here
}
```

Note: you should also use

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />`

Comment: Thanks but Sorry, i forgot to mention. I'm not supposed to use media query inside css.

Comment: @Wisam : then why you mentioned `I'm using media queries, but styling for mobile view reflects in desktop also.`????

Comment: @Wisam actually, you are — it's the only place you can use them.

Comment: `initial-scale` should be `1`, `.0` is redundant part.

Answer (score 0):

Since your requirement is desktop, I suggest using media queries, targeting **height of the viewport** because landscape mode way conflict the width for iPad and laptop.

Something like:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) , screen and (min-height: 768px) {
   /* styles here */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You say « *styling for mobile view reflects in desktop also. :)* », but that's not strictly true — people mostly use `max-width` or `min-width` statements in their media queries (which will take effect depending on browser viewport size), but you can also use `max-device-width` and `min-device-width`. When you decide a device is a desktop is still difficult: media queries alone can't tell you whether a device is portable. But size is half the battle:

```
@media (max-device-width: 640px /* or whatever you decide on */ ){
     /* fancy scrollbars */
}
```